# How do I properly set the value of my timepicker directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a timepicker directive in AngularJS that uses the jquery timepicker plugin. (I am unable to get any of the existing angular TimePickers to work in IE8).

So far, I was able to get the directive to work as far as updating the scope when a time is selected. However, what I need to accomplish now is getting the input to display the time, rather than the text of the model's value when the page first loads. See below:

this is what shows: [image]
this is what I want: [image]

Here is my directive:

```
   'use strict';

    playgroundApp.directive('timePicker', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: "?ngModel",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                element.timepicker();
            //controller.$setViewValue(element.timepicker('setTime', ngModel.$modelValue));
            //ngModel.$render = function() {
            //    var date = ngModel.$modelValue ? new Date(ngModel.$modelValue) : null;
            //};

            //if (date) {
            //    controller.$setViewValue(element.timepicker('setTime', date));
            //}

            element.on('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    controller.$setViewValue(element.timepicker('getTime', new Date()));
                });
            });
        },
    };
})
```

The commented code is what I've attempted, but it doesn't work. I get an error that reads, ngModel is undefined. So, to clarify, when the page first loads, if there is a model for that input field, I want the input to show only the time, as it does after a value is selected.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Ok, after making some trial and error changes, my link function looks like this:

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        if (!controller) {
            return;
        }

        element.timepicker();

        var val = controller.$modelValue;

        var date = controller.$modelValue ? new Date(controller.$modelValue) : null;

        controller.$setViewValue(element.timepicker('setTime', controller.$modelValue));
        //ngModel.$render = function () {
        //    var date = ngModel.$modelValue ? new Date(ngModel.$modelValue) : null;
        //};

        if (date) {
            controller.$setViewValue(element.timepicker('setTime', date));
        }

        element.on('change', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                controller.$setViewValue(element.timepicker('getTime', new Date()));
            });
        });
    },
```

This doesn't give me any errors, but the $modelValue is always NaN. Here is my controller code:

```
   $scope.startTime = new Date();
$scope.endTime = new Date();
```

and the relevant html:

```
    <input id="startTime" ng-model="startTime" time-picker/>
    <input id="endTime" ng-model="endTime" time-picker />
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Which timepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery

Answer (score 3):

I spent several days trying with the same plugin without getting results and eventually I found another:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

It works perfectly using the following directive:

```
app.directive('timepicker', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
              $(function(){
                  element.timepicker({
                     onSelect:function (time) {
                         ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(time);
                         scope.$apply();
                     }
                  });
              });
         }
   }
});
```

I hope you find useful.